# Translating sscanf() references in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have this code:

```
sscanf ("45 , ignore_this % C read_in_this**", "%d , %*s %% %c %5s %s",
&i, &c, string, &string[5]);
```

and when I look at the variable assignments, I get

```
c = C
i = 45
string = read_in_this**
string + 5 = in_this**
```

I'm confused about how `&i`, `&c`, `string`, and `&string[5]` were assigned. My step-by-step interpretation/questions:

- `&i` -> `%d` -> "45"
- `%*s` is skipped because of the "*", so "ignore_this" is ignored.
- Is `%%` skipped as well? Why isn't `&c` assigned to `%%`? What happens to the "%" from the input string?
- `&c` -> `%c` -> "C"
- `string` -> `%5s` -> "read_in_this**" but what is the point of the '5'? Why can't it just be `%s`?
- Not sure what `&string[5]` does.
- What does `string + 5` do exactly?

Would really appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: `%%` matches `%` verbatim...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala if you follow the assignments, &c should be % - does % not get assigned then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `*scanf`, whitespace characters eat all whitespace and `%` starts a conversion specifier. Other characters in the format must match the input 1-to-1. `%%` matches a `%` from input.

Thus:

- `%d` converts a decimal integer from input (45), storing it to `i`.
- eats white space
- `%*s` parses and *discards* a string that is delimited by whitespace (`ignore_this`)
- `,` matches the comma
- eats white space
- `%c` reads in one character, storing it to `char` - here `'C'`, stored to `c`
- eats white space again

Now at this point the input remaining is `read_in_this**`. The conversion specifier `%5s` parses an up to 5 characters long space-delimited string - here it will match `read_`; these characters will be stored in `string[0]` ... `string[4]`; `string[5]` will receive the string-terminating `\0`. The input remaining is `in_this**`. Now the   will discard any whitespace (there isn't any, so nothing is discarded).

Finally the last `%s` will read in a whitespace-delimited string `in_this_**` and store it to the memory that *starts* from the address of `string[5]` - i.e. overwriting the terminating null character with `i` - and so forth. You can experiment what will happen if you replace `&string[5]` with `&string[3]` for example.

Comment: @Amy you might consider [accepting my answer too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/190417).